# How to create query builder from SQL statement

Tags: laravel

My SQL statement as below show:

```
SELECT YEAR(`UNIT`.sold_date) AS SOLD_YEAR 
FROM pams_unit AS `UNIT` 
WHERE `UNIT`.status_id=3 AND YEAR(`UNIT`.sold_date)>=2012 
GROUP BY SOLD_YEAR
```

And then, after i change it to Query Builder

```
$year = DB::table('pams_unit')
      ->selectRaw('year(sold_date) as year')
      ->where([
                ['status_id', '=', '3'],
                ['year(sold_date)', '>=', '2012'],
             ])
       ->groupBy('year');
```

May i ask my query builder is correct or not compared with the sql statement?

Comment: You need to call `->get()` at the end.

Comment: Thansk you, but now it said `Unknown column 'year(sold_date)' in 'where clause'`

Comment: yea , I appended already. Then in my where clause, I wrote `['year', '>=', '2012']`, but it still showing same error `Unknown column 'year' in 'where clause`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using the following changes:

```
$year = DB::table('pams_unit')->selectRaw('year(sold_date) as year')
                              ->where('status_id' => 3)
                              ->whereRaw('year(sold_date) >= 2012')
                              ->groupBy('year')
                              ->get();
```